# what is the best method for real time tracking of GPS location rather than calling plot map function on time loop?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps, real-time

I had developed a **real-time GPS location tracking** system in which the mobile devices integrated with GPS device send location information to web server obtained at database and it is being plotted in Google map by calling the function to plot GPS data in map periodically as **function is called repeatedly over specific time interval**.

On the user end we can watch the location update like the **plotters blinking** and changing the location in Google map.

Is there any other best method to show real-time GPS location on Google map?

Any method to make the plotters move without blinking, like continuously flowing through map?

Any piece of code is appreciated & thanks in advance.

Comment: did the answer helped you??

Comment: @geekCode, nope. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to store the location history in database, make it short duration and lets call it Location Frame. Now you have a from and to coordinate positions to move your plotters in the map. update the frame by setting a frequency in which the new frame can be applied when plotter have approached the destination of last frame. Build pragram on this logic. hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this code into a service and it only get the cordinates... they are never rendered into any map....

```
private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
    Location mLastLocation;

    public LocationListener(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        sLat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
        sLong = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        Speed = Double.toString(location.getSpeed());
        sAlt = Double.toString(location.getAltitude());
        sTime = Double.toString(location.getTime());
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location + localTime);
        mLastLocation.set(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}

LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    initializeLocationManager();
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[1]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    IMEI = mngr.getDeviceId();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void initializeLocationManager() {
    Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

}